# how to clip text of the RichTexBox

Tags: silverlight

hi I have RichTextBox bind to description(html format) from database and it is read only. I just need to show First line from description. How to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

As Silverlight has no way of measuring the width of fonts, you'll need to take an arbitrary amount of the text, and simply `Substring()` it.

Comment: using substring I am showing 100 characters of the text in first line. but if I increase Font size of the text, it wraps to next line. I just need to show first line irrespective of font size.

Comment: @Jolly you could turn off text wrapping in the textbox